# Counting "deflected" permutations: Part I

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, sequences-and-series, permutations, enumerative-combinatorics

Let $\mathfrak{S}_n$ denote the group of permutations on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Now, introduce the sets
$$\mathcal{A}_n^{(k)}:=\{\pi\in\mathfrak{S}_n: -1\leq \pi(j)-j\leq k,\,\forall j\}.$$

I would like to ask:

> **Question.** What is the cardinality $\#\mathcal{A}_n^{(k)}$ of these sets, in terms of $n$ and $k$?

Comment: It is past my bedtime, but isn't this just the number of compositions of $n$ into parts at most $k+1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that $-1 <= \pi(j) - j$ means that an element of the permutation can
only shift one position to the right.  This means that a permutation satisfying
the lower bound is composed of nonoverlapping factors of the form
$i+m,i,i+1,\dots,i+m-1$ that start at position $i$.  The upper bound restricts the
size of $m \le k$.  Since the size of the factor is $m+1$ the number of permutations
in $\mathfrak{S}_n$
satisfying $-1 \le \pi(j) - j \le k$ is just the number of compositions of $n$
whose largest part is less than or equal to $k+1$.

I don't know of a nice closed form, but
$$\#\mathcal{A}_n^{(k)}=[x^n]\frac{1-x}{1-2x+x^{k+2}}$$

Comment: These are the $k$-bonacci numbers, as in Fibonacci, tribonacci etc.