# Counting "deflected" permutations: Part II

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, permutations, enumerative-combinatorics

This is the second sequel to my earlier [question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272312/counting-deflected-permutations-part-i). Although the the current problem appears very similar, the answer is certainly different as experiments indicate.

As usual, let $\mathfrak{S}_n$ be the set of permutations on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and introduce the sets
$$\mathcal{B}_n^{(k)}:=\{\pi\in\mathfrak{S}_{n+k}: -k\leq \pi(j)-j\leq n,\,\forall j\}.$$

I would like to ask:

> **Question.** What is the cardinality $\#\mathcal{B}_n^{(k)}$ of these sets, in terms of $n$ and $k$?

**Note.** One cute (but simple) property is that $\#\mathcal{B}_n^{(k)}=\#\mathcal{B}_k^{(n)}$.

Comment: The second comment in [A099594](http://oeis.org/A099594) is this problem.  The referenced paper appears to give a proof.